# A sentence false in a field of characteristic $0$ but true in all fields of positive characteristic?

Tags: logic, field-theory, model-theory

Consider the language $L=\{+,\cdot, 0, 1\}$ of rings. It is easy to show using compactness that if $\sigma$ is a sentence that holds in all fields of characteristic $0$, there is some $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $\sigma$ holds for all fields of characteristic $p\geq N$. A sort of converse would be, if $\sigma$ is a sentence that holds in all fields of positive characteristic, $\sigma$ is true in all fields of characteristic $0$. I have no idea how to come up with a counterexample or a proof of this.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The four square theorem yields the following theorem in positive characteristic:

$$\exists a,b,c,d : a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + 1 = 0$$

Comment: We can't both be right...

Comment: @Asaf: I show there exists a statement true in positive characteristic that is false in at least one field of $0$. You show that every sentence true in positive characteristic is true in at least one field of characteristic $0$.

Comment: Drats. All that wrist strain for nothing! :-)

Comment: @Hurkyl It's not immediately obvious to me that this holds in the fields $GF(p^k)$ for $k>1$, but I might be missing something.

Comment: @Alex: $GF(p) \subseteq GF(p^k)$

Comment: @AsafKaragila I can't believe you typed that out on an iPhone. I can't even do this LaTeX stuff on my iPad. That would drive me nuts.

Comment: @Thomas: Asaf is notorious that way. I shouldn’t be surprised if he’s typed more answers on his iPhone than any other two people put together.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't know if what Brian says is true, but I once wrote a really long answer. When I left a surprised comment it got more votes than the answer. :-)

Answer (score 17):

The canonical solution is to use the fact that $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ has a solution in every finite field, which can be proved by a simple counting argument.  That equation is solvable in any field of positive characteristic, because it is solvable in the prime subfield.  But not in $\mathbb R$.

This is the same idea as the other answer, but the proof of solvability is easier than the 4-squares theorem.

For the general question of what can be done in first-order theory of rings to separate characteristic 0 and characteristic $p$, there are brilliant results on this (and several other matters) in Bjorn Poonen's paper at http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507486 .

Comment: I've seen this theorem used as a lemme on the way to proving the four square theorem.