# Model theory of fields of characteristic $0$

Tags: logic, field-theory, first-order-logic, model-theory

I am stuck on the following problem:

> A sentence is valid in the class of fields of characteristic $0$ iff it is true for all fields of characteristic $p>n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now, the one direction follows from a simple application of compactness, as the class of fields of characteristic $0$ is $\Delta$-elementary:

---

Let $\phi_F$ be the sentence expressing "is a field" and $\chi_p$ be the sentence expressing "has characteristic $p$". Take

$$\Gamma=\{\phi_F\}\cup\{\neg\chi_p\mid p\text{ prime}\},$$

then $\mathfrak{A}\models\Gamma$ iff $\mathfrak{A}$ is a field of characteristic $0$.

Now, suppose $\phi$ is valid in the class of fields of characteristic $0$, that is $\Gamma\models\phi$, then by compactness there is a finite subset $\Phi\subset\Gamma$ such that $\Phi\models\phi$ but

$$\Phi\subseteq\{\phi_F,\neg\chi_{p_1},\dots,\neg\chi_{p_n}\}\models\phi$$

where $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime. Then especially we have that $\phi$ is true in every field of characteristic $>p_n$.

---

Now, the converse direction is giving me problems. A hint I have received told me to assume that $\phi$ would be true in all characteristics $>n$ and then to apply compactness. Another, to apply compactness to the negation.

However, with both I have achieved almost no results. I am not sure of how to approach that.

---

EDIT: With the converse direction, I mean the following:

> If a sentence is not valid in the class of fields of characteristic $0$, then for all $n\in\mathbb N$ there is a prime $p>n$ such that $\phi$ is not true in a field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Anything about the newer answer I wrote?

Comment: The problem is that the converse is false. See here for examples: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332433/a-sentence-false-in-a-field-of-characteristic-0-but-true-in-all-fields-of-posi?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (that actually answers this problem).

**Lemma 1.** The statement "$F$ is a field of characteristics $0$" is not expressible as a single sentence in the language of fields.

*Proof.* If it were, take an ultraproduct of all finite prime fields using a free ultrafilter. Easily, this is a field of characteristics $0$. If there was a single sentence asserting this, it would have to hold in infinitely many of the finite fields, which is impossible.

*Remark.* Note that this actually shows that no single sentence implies the characteristics of the field is $0$ over the theory of fields with characteristics "at least $n$" for any finite $n$.

---

Now suppose that $\psi$ is true in some field of characteristics $0$. Since being of characteristics $0$ is not equivalent to any single sentence in the language of fields, it cannot be that $\psi$ implies (over the theory of fields) that the characteristics is $0$. In particular, it means that it is consistent with a finite characteristics.

But since $\psi$ is also true in some field of characteristics $0$, it is consistent with "the characteristics of the field is at least $n$" for any finite $n$, and therefore there are arbitrarily large finite characteristics where $\psi$ is consistent.

Finally, take $\psi=\lnot\phi$.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your last assertion that the statement is consistent with "characteristic is at least n
". Although this is true, it doesn't ensure that there is a model of finite characteristic. The problem is the "at least". The consistency is also witnessed by a model of characteristic 0. I don't see a reason why a model of finite characteristic should exist (and in fact, it doesn't always exists; see my link in my comment under the question)